# AU3Recorder not running

Tags: windows, automation, autoit, autoit-recorder

I downloaded [the latest version](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) and ran full installation using default settings. Then I downloaded [SciTE4AutoIt3.exe](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/). I created and saved a new .au3 file. When I click the AU3Recorder option in Tools menu nothing happens (I expected the recorder window to come up).

I searched `C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\SciTE` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Extras` but can't find AU3Recorder.exe there so that's probably why it didn't run. I also tried reinstalling those two application already. How to get the recorder to work on Windows 8.1 Enterprise?

I found the zip file for AU3Recorder.exe and put it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Extras\Au3Record\`. The recorder window now opens but when I click record I get an error popup that says "DLL load Failed". What DLL file is meant and where I can get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I downloaded [the zip file](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/archive/autoit/autoit-v3.3.8.1.zip) instead of the install file.

- Open the zip and file go to `install/Extras`.
- Copy entire `Au3Record` folder.
- Paste in `C:\Program Files(x86)\AutoIt3\Extras\`.

It worked without even closing AutoIt. I did not have to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable, but I may have installed it at an earlier time.

Answer (score 5):

Summary of steps that I followed:

1. Downloaded AutoIt.
2. Downloaded Script Editor.
3. Downloaded [zip file](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/archive/autoit/autoit-v3.3.8.1.zip)
4. Copied entire `Au3recorder` folder into `Program Files (x86)\AutoIT\Extras\`.
5. Rebooted system.
6. Created new au3 script.
7. Saved.
8. Went to `Tools` > `Auto Recorder` and confirmed that auto recorder appeared.

Comment: would be nice but I pasted the Folder but I can not find it. Please give a screen shot of where to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the last version of the zip to include plugin is [**here**](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/archive/autoit/autoit-v3.3.14.0.zip)